# Solving Heuristically Using Greedy Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, greedy

I have a question on a test review thats asks "Which of the following is solved heuristically by a greedy method?"

A. Unweighted interval scheduling

B. 0/1 knapsack

C. Fractional knapsack

D. Huffman code

I'm was able to narrow it down to A,C, or D because I know 0/1 knapsack use Dynamic programing. My best guess would be C because I THINK A and D can be solved optimally using greedy algorithms.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's correct.

The Fractional knapsack problem can be solved by choosing greedily.

Comment: But cant unweighted interval scheduling and Huffman code also be solved using a greedy algorithm? 

Is it because it can't be solved optimally?